# Undergrad/grad (paid) internships in bioacoustics

Tags: internship, learning-experience

I'm often asked by undergraduate students about internship opportunities in bioacoustics but most of these positions are unpaid, which I personally do not advertise as I think it's exploitative & exclusionary (a conversation for a different day...). But it's always difficult trying to find out about those rare paid internship positions (for either undergraduate or graduate students).

Does anyone know of particular bioacoustics projects or organizations that have a regular cycle of these paid internship positions? Anything globally. Or (for the US) any universities/lab groups that consistently have REUs (Research Experience for Undergrads, NSF program) in bioacoustics? I'm mostly looking for undergrad opportunities but would be great to hear about grad internship positions as well! Thanks!

Comment: In the UK, internships are usually part of a course ("project"), so students should pay as part of the University fees. In France, current law forces any employee (including Universities) to pay an intern if the project duration is ≥ 8weeks

Comment: Is this really something specific to bioacoustics or should it be asked on [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for internships specifically in bioacoustics

Comment: And interesting re: the European laws. In the US pretty much all field or labwork type  ecology/field bio internships are unpaid.

Comment: I would be interested too as a graduate. In Europe is not so easy too to find something not-to-pay for, even worse if you want to be paid. MARMAM is the only one were I saw some opportunities

Answer (score 13):

Scripps Institution of Oceanography in San Diego, CA has a paid [summer internship program](https://scripps.ucsd.edu/mpl/mpl-summer-internship-program) for undergraduates in the Marine Physical Laboratory (MPL). We see a regular cycle of students interested in bioacoustics come through. Caveats being the cost of living in San Diego and you have to be a U.S. citizen.

Answer (score 9):

In the United States, NOAA (National Oceanic & Atmospheric Administration) has several paid internships/fellowships. Topics vary, but there are several supported in bioacoustics every year. Students must be U.S. Citizens, and requirements vary by internship.  For more info, see https://www.noaa.gov/education/opportunities/students

Answer (score 8):

The National Park Service (U.S.) has a Scientists in Parks program that often has bioacoustics-relevant internships open to undergraduates (although not exclusively -- can also be open to recent graduates, graduate students -- depends on the specific positions). These opportunity calls come out a few times per year, and typically bioacoustics-relevant positions will have the title "Acoustic Assistant". Internships may range from 12-52 weeks and usually are on-site in a park, but occasionally can be remote. Interns must be U.S. citizens or permanent U.S. residents.

The application period has closed for the latest call, but internships can be searched here to see examples:
https://www.nps.gov/subjects/science/scientists-in-parks-all-opportunities.htm

The internships are administered through the Geological Society of America (GSA), and can be located by typing *Scientists in Parks National Park Service* into a search engine.

Answer (score 7):

For the ad hoc paid internships as opposed to regularly occurring institutional ones, it seems like quite a few have been posted through MARMAM lately. https://lists.uvic.ca/mailman/listinfo/marmam