# High school level internship/programs in the Bioacoustics field?

Tags: internship, learning-experience

I am a high school student who has had the great opportunity to be introduced to a mentor in the Bioacoustics field. Through this mentorship, I have learned how to use acoustic software (PAMguard and Matlab) to better understand marine ecosystems and the behavior of odontocetes. By working on this research, I have found that I absolutely love marine acoustic ecology. I believe being introduced to the field and being able to work on research at such a young age has been such a fascinating and empowering experience.

Does anyone know of research camps or internships that are available to high school students in the Bioacoustics field? I am looking for opportunities to share with my younger peers who have an interest in Biology and Ecology so they can find a home in Bioacoustics too.

Comment: Just highlighting this similar post, which asks the same question for undergrad level (some of these org's may have high school level opportunities as well)- https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/767/undergrad-grad-paid-internships-in-the-usa-in-bioacoustics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you live in a town with a university, see if there are any labs or professors working in bioacoustics or marine ecology and reach out. There are a couple professors I know that have high school students working in their labs so it's worth a shot to ask! Bioacousticians (and all scientists really) always need more helping hands :).

You could also try looking at high school opportunities at zoos/aquariums/nature centers if you are near any - many have high school experiences. It wouldn't necessarily be bioacoustics, but I think getting yourself any animal experience is worthwhile and will nonetheless give you a more comprehensive knowledge base!

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely reach out to UC Berkeley to see if there is any bio acoustic work!!

Comment: You might try the Elias lab - https://nature.berkeley.edu/news/2021/02/studying-spider-responses-sound-elias-lab

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Carly Batist - reaching out to local professors, graduate students or other research labs is a great idea!

I co-lead a long-term (1 semester - 3 year) high school bioacoustics research program called [Seatech](https://www.annesimonis.com/seatech). We are a collective of bioacoustics researchers who mentor high school students in bioacoustics research. We mainly work with Mt. Edgecumbe High School in Sitka, Alaska, but we use a combination of in-person and virtual instruction, and we are open to expanding to other schools, particularly if there are interested teachers & administrators.

It's a little known fact that high school students can do excellent research, and I've found that together we are able to accomplish so much more than I could ever do on my own.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input and I hope more high schoolers can join the field!!